# How can I send keys to another application using delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, winapi, keyboard, delphi-7

Ok, so Pretty much i am trying to send keystrokes of a string from and edit box to the active window and the enter key after. does anyone here know a working method of doing this in delphi 7?

I have been searching for about an hour and a half for this now and i cant seem to find anything and the stuff I have found is ether for newer versions of delphi, or it just doesn't work. I have tried TTouchKeyboard but that's only for delphi 10 and newer.

Comment: Does it have to be Delphi? Look at Autohotkey.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've used this to send text to an annoying popup 3G application with no interface, its a hack be we wern't left with any option.

```
procedure TForm1.TypeMessage(Msg: string);
var
  CapsOn: boolean;
  i: integer;
  ch: char;
  shift: boolean;
  key: short;
begin
  CapsOn := (GetKeyState( VK_CAPITAL ) and $1) <> 0;

  for i:=1 to length(Msg) do
  begin
    ch := Msg[i];
    ch := UpCase(ch);

    if ch <> Msg[i] then
    begin
      if CapsOn then
      begin
        keybd_event( VK_SHIFT, 0, 0, 0 );
      end;
      keybd_event( ord(ch), 0, 0, 0 );
      keybd_event( ord(ch), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 );
      if CapsOn then
      begin
        keybd_event( VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 );
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      key := VKKeyScan( ch );
      // UpperCase
      if ((not CapsOn) and (ch>='A') and (ch <= 'Z')) or
         ((key and $100) > 0) then
      begin
        keybd_event( VK_SHIFT, 0, 0, 0 );
      end;
      keybd_event( key, 0, 0, 0 );
      keybd_event( key, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 );
      if ((not CapsOn) and (ch>='A') and (ch <= 'Z')) or
         ((key and $100) > 0) then
      begin
        keybd_event( VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 );
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

hope that helps

**UPDATE**

Edited to allow other characters (non alpha ) ie shifted numerals !"£$ etc.

Comment: Thaks so much! :) that worked! :) awesome man. but does anyone know how i would send the enter key?

Comment: sure just call TypeMessage( char(VK_RETURN) ); or add char(VK_RETURN) to your message

Comment: this way doesnt type any characters like / . or : how could i get those to work?

Comment: ok connor editied to allow those types of chars, didn't need them in my app but it does them now.

Comment: oops, 3rd time lucky, try that

Comment: Thanks so much! it works! :) and haha i was working on a kind of a filter to check if it was a letter or not and to not cap it if its not a letter. (mine did not work) thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

See [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. You will need to perform translation between chars and keyboard scan codes, but internet is full of information on this.

Unless you need to emulate *typing*, it makes sense to send WM_SETTEXT to the edit box window and then send Enter as a keyboard. This will let you avoid dealing with scancodes.

Answer (score 0):

Use SendKeys() from the unit SNDKEY32.PAS on the Delphi 7 installation CD. In case you cannot find your CD, look [here](https://code.google.com/p/theunknownones/source/browse/trunk/Libraries/CommonTools/sndkey32.pas). Works fine for me (Delphi7 on Windows 7).